# $.ajax call working fine in IE8 and Doesn't work in firefox and chrome browsers

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

here is my code

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET", 
    url: 'http://devserver:7995/stdpart/services/GetAllPartsWithFilter',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonPartsData,
    success: fnGetPartsData, 
    error: PartsLoadError  
});
```

This is code working fine in IE8, But getting failed in Firefox and Chrome browsers. When i, inspect the XHR object, it's saying the status code code is 0.  I have checked all other questions, none of them are helped me to identify the issue.

Let me know, if i am doing any thing wrong in this code. If $.ajax has some compatibility issues, then please suggest something equivalent to it.

**Update:**
We found one solution at
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/12/21/json-dynamic-script-tag.html

It is using the concept of **Dynamic Scripting**. We have done the same thing in our application, then every thing seems to be working now. Yet to analyze fully.

Comment: Are you sure you are returning valid JSON? I had cases where IE evaluated malformed JSON (like `{ "key" : "value", }`) where other browser fail (as they should). Any error messages?

Comment: what is the error , what is the  jsonPartsData ???

Comment: Actually you cannot make Ajax calls to an external site, unless you have a specific setup.

Comment: @FelixKling you can ... just use JSONP ...

Comment: @Andreas: Right, I'd say this belongs to special setup ;) It does not look like the OP is using JSONP, so the only other way is to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin ` header.

Comment: When i check the error in Chrome Browser developer tools, it's returning the error message like this --- "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://devserver:7995/stdpart/services/GetAllPartsWithFilter?_=1325492196886. Origin http://ie1alt5nhm2bs is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: I think, because of this only, it's not working in Firefox also. How to fix this security issue?

Comment: That's what I'm saying.... you cannot access third party domains. Search here on SO how to solve this, it was already asked quite often.

Comment: How to add custom headers to my $.ajax call? I got confused a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is because of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). you cannot use ajax to call external sites. if you really want to use, you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Or you can use serverside proxy for this. means, call external site in the server side and do ajax call to the that webservice.

---

***UPDATE:***

create webserveice in your site and in the webmethod put following code

```
string proxyURL = "http://devserver:7995/stdpart/services/GetAllPartsWithFilter";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(proxyURL);
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode.ToString().ToLower() == "ok")
{
    Stream content = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader contentReader = new StreamReader(content);         
    return contentReader.ReadToEnd();
}
return string.Empty;
```

then access local service using your code.

[for more information please refer this link](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html)

Comment: Or use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (which is not supported in all browsers though).

Comment: Can you please share some sample code, if you have. I Have tried few examples, but nothing worked for me :(

Comment: if you want to use `JSONP`, you have to change the server code as well. easyest way is using serverside proxy for this. try this link for more details how to use serverside proxy, see the updated answer

Comment: @Dinesh: is this sample is fine for you? or do i need to update more?

Comment: @Sandamal: we are trying the wrapper services as exactly you have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use the [jQuery ajaxTransport extension](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) that uses XDomainRequest for IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

I do think there is anything wrong with your code.

Please see [Pure JavaScript Ajax calls](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)

Different libraries implement Ajax APIs in different manner. So, in your case it must be a problem with the version of jquery you are using.

Please try Pure JavaScript Ajax call, and see if it works on all browsers. If it does, then there is a problem with jquery which you do not want to spend time on. If it does not then you are missing something.

Comment: With the pure JavaScript also, i am getting the same issue. I have customized the header by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin and some other parameters. Nothing worked :(

Comment: Can you confirm that pure JS Ajax DOES work in IE and NOT in chrome/ff/safari ?