# Jquery.post not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a javascript that loads a webpage from a web application using Jquery.post. I display the page in iframe . The webpage gets displayed in IE  but not in firefox. I tried using Firebug but there is no error , it has a 302 OK note. I tried changing the Jquery source that also  did not work. Tried JSON that also did not work. Its more than 3 days i am trying  to fix this issue. I tried lot of methods but it was not fruitful.

```
 <html>
  <head>
     <script      type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery1.4.2.min.js">
     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function callajax()
    {
       var iframe =document.createElement("iframe");
       iframe.style.width="100%";
       iframe.style.height="100%";
       //app.getContentEl().appendChild(iframe);
       document.body.appendChild(iframe);
       jQuery.post('http://localhost:9090/simpleapp/formproc1',     {'param':'rajat'},function(html){


        var doc =iframe.contentWindow.document;
        doc.write(html);
        doc.close();
        });
        }



        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
         <p>Start typing a name in the input field below:</p>
         <span></span>
         <div id="display"></div>
         First name:

         <input type="text" />

         <button onclick="callajax()">Click me</button>
         </body>
         </html>
```

i  will also enclose the post method since it might also be an erroneous one.

```
      doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      String par = request.getParameter("param");

       System.out.print("Hiii this is inside POST method");

        //out.println("<data><param>"+par+"</param></data>");

        //out.println(par);

        //out.flush();

        //System.out.print(par);

         response.sendRedirect("first.jsp");

         // out.println("{\"redirect\":\"first.jsp\"}");

         }
```

Comment: try putting alert and check if the method is called after button click.

Comment: Describe how it "doesn't work".  Does it create the iframe? Does the iframe get populated at all? Did you try calling the jQuery.post function by hand in firebug?

Comment: thanks a lot for your very swift response. Firebug does nt show any error . But the response is empty.The request gets through successfully.And the iframe is created but the web page is not populated in the iframe. Can u help me now

Answer (score 1):

this is because of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). you cannot use ajax to call external sites. if you really want to use, you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Or you can use serverside proxy for this. means, call external site in the server side and do ajax call to the that webservice.

see my answer,
[$.ajax call working fine in IE8 and Doesn't work in firefox and chrome browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698682/ajax-call-working-fine-in-ie8-and-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome-browsers/8698786#8698786)

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But  if JSONP is used , what will happen if the POSt method response is a webpage. Will the web  page be displayed in iframe?  i mean  if web pages can  be passed as  arguments the call back function.Please throw some light on this .