# Getting json via ajax in a specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

A javascript function on a webpage requires data in the following format:

```
// Javascript
var data = [
            {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"},
            {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"},
            {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"}
];
```

At the moment, this variable is hardcoded in the javascript file and everything works fine.
In the second step, I want to improve it by requesting the data from a server via jQuery's ajax functionality instead of using the hardcoded variable, because of course, until now, the data is static.

So I put a text file on my server, it contains:

```
// textfile on server
[
            {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"},
            {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"},
            {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"}
];
```

And apart from that, a PHP script. the PHP script sets its content type to application/json and prints the textfile.

In Javascript, i tried something like this:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://www.myserver.com/output.php", function() {
    alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

Unfortunately, I only get an "error" alert and the two complete alerts.

So I have two questions:

- what's wrong about the ajax call, maybe I should deliver the data in text/plain instead of application/json?
- Apart from that Ajax stuff: as I mentioned above, a specific javascript function requires a variable/data in the format `var data = [ { "A" : "B:}, { "A" : "B:}];` . Is the result of this query (if it would work..) the same format?

The only requirement is that I need both a success and an error handler, just a success handler is not enough.

Thank you

Comment: thank you, the dots were typos I only did on stackoverflow, and I removed the semicolon. anything else? Still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are accessing it through cross domain and it violates [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

[follow this link to learn how to overcome this.](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html)

see my answer on this question
[$.ajax call working fine in IE8 and Doesn't work in firefox and chrome browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698682/ajax-call-working-fine-in-ie8-and-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome-browsers/8698786#8698786)

and your JSON should be in following format.

```
[
   {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"},
   {"AKey" : "AVal","BKey" : "BVal"},
   {"AKey" : "AVal", "BKey" : "BVal"}
];
```

Comment: All of the content is located on "myserver.com", so there should not be a problem or am I wrong? apart from that, it works in none of the browsers.

Comment: put the url like `/output.php` and format the JSON like above.

Comment: Ok, I changed it accordingly to your post - but I removed the semicolon, I think it isn't valid JSON. When I load my out.php via http://jsonviewer.stack.hu directly from myserver.com/out.php, the viewer can indeed present the data so I think its valid. Apart from that, it still doesn't work. Is there a way I can find out why jquery displays an error alert? edit: with chrome web inspector I found out that jquery successfully loads the out.php with HTTP 200 and the correct body..

Comment: Thank you, it works now! It seems there was a caching problem with the json textfile on my server..

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a subset of JavaScript.  While this

```
[
            {"AKey" : "AVal". "BKey" : "BVal"},
            {"AKey" : "AVal". "BKey" : "BVal"},
            {"AKey" : "AVal". "BKey" : "BVal"}
];
```

may be Javascript, the semicolon means it's *not* JSON.  Also, the periods need to be replaced with commas.

Comment: thank you, the dots were typos I only did on stackoverflow, and I removed the semicolon. anything else? Still doesn't work :(