# Cross origin policy error with jQuery get

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I'm having trouble with the API for Last.FM.

The following code is on my localhost and works.  I get the expected result.

```
var url="http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxx&format=json&callback=?";
                $(document).ready(function()
                 {
                    $.getJSON(url, function(data)
                    {

                    });
                 });
```

However when I set up a small webservice, say "www.example.com/hello", the following script on my localhost does not work.  (It should return "hello".)

```
var url="www.example.com/hello";
                    $(document).ready(function()
                     {
                        $.get(url, function(data)
                        {

                        });
                     });
```

Now, I get a cross origin policy problem.

Answer (score 1):

for more information see this [How to use Cross domain Ajax request](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html) and my answer for this question [$.ajax call working fine in IE8 and Doesn't work in firefox and chrome browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698682/ajax-call-working-fine-in-ie8-and-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome-browsers/8698786#8698786)

Comment: But how is it that the first peice of code works wells and while that as soon that i changes the url, it doesn't, do i have to make any modifications on the server side

Comment: first one is JSONP enabled service and second one is not. if you follow the tutorial you will understand how to enable it.

Comment: lol, don't worry, if the answer is correct, i'll surely tick it :)