# Jquery Ajax call problemn with Data Type 

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, api, opencalais

I'm using Jquery to try to grab some data from the [Open Calais](http://www.opencalais.com/) api, but if I cannot get a valid response. If I use data type "script" I get an error of "missing ; before statement. If I use data type "xml" or anything else I get a 403 error from the Open Calais server.

I decided to try the "script" data type based on the last entry on this [Calais forum post](http://www.opencalais.com/forums/known-issues/using-javascript-send-content)

Please don't hold back on the critiques and comments regarding my code. I'm leaning as I go.

My code:

```
var baseUrl="http://api.opencalais.com/enlighten/calais.asmx/Enlighten";
var licenseID="wt8h3w3pt333eewdwsyuhut6";
var content="In response to a legislative provision in a bill reauthorizing the FAA, the agency has launched a comment period as it selects six test sites to evaluate unmanned aircraft systems. The focus of the proceeding will be determining the location of the test sites along with establishing...";
var PARMS="&contentType=text/xml&outputFormat=xml/rdf"
var PostDatavar = "?licenseID="+licenseID+"&content="+encodeURIComponent(content)+PARMS;
var componentURL=baseUrl+PostDatavar;

function sendIt(sendData){
$.ajax({
    url:componentURL,
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"script",
    success:function(data){
            alert(data)); 
            console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(){
    alert("it's broken");
    }}
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

this is because of the same origin policy. you cannot use simple ajax requests for cross domain requests. for more information see my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698682/ajax-call-working-fine-in-ie8-and-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome-browsers/8698786#8698786). you can learn more about how to overcome this issue by following [this tutorial](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html).

Comment: Of course! Thanks for pointing that out. I'll run it thru php and post back to here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following function as there were some syntax errors in the function that was written in the script posted above.

```
function sendIt(sendData){
$.ajax({
    url:componentURL,
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"script",
    success:function(data){
            alert(data); 
            console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(){
    alert("it's broken");
    }}
);
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks identical to mine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes there was some problem with the opening and closing of the braces that are used.