# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/sample.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: javascript, iis

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,xx,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Author</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("book");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
  txt=txt + "<tr>";     
  xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("author");
    {
    try
      {
      txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
      }
    catch (er)
      {
      txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
      }
    }
    xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("title");
    {
    try
      {
      txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
      }
    catch (er)
      {
      txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
      }
    }
  txt=txt + "</tr>";
  }
txt=txt + "</table>";
document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="txtCDInfo">
<button onclick="loadXMLDoc('http://localhost:8081/sample.xml')">GetDetails</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have written above lines of code for showing xml file data.And it was deployed in iis server.Whenever i wanted to access xml file,It is showing above error.Where am i doing wrong mistake.What i have to write in url position for getting xml file.If i write only file name like sample.xml.It showing error like Access denied.

Comment: Is the page also served on port 8081?

Comment: no.only xml page is placed in iis server.and .html saved in local drive.

Comment: Both the html and the xml must be from the same server (technically same url domain, can be different machines). In your case the page has a file url and the xml has localhost:8081 url so the browser will not allow you to use xmlhttprequest due to different domains. Also, xmlhttprequest cannot work with file url (not without modifying advanced browser settings and not with all browsers)

Comment: I strongly suggest you reed Chamika's answer because it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). you cannot use ajax to call external sites. if you really want to use, you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Or you can use serverside proxy for this. means, call external site in the server side and do ajax call to the that webservice.
For more details see my answer on following question,
[$.ajax call working fine in IE8 and Doesn't work in firefox and chrome browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698682/ajax-call-working-fine-in-ie8-and-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome-browsers/8698786#8698786)

Comment: above code is working fine in IE,But in Chrome and FF not working.Is there any browser fault..

Comment: hope you can read the answer i have given. go to the linked answer and you will find the solution. no browser issue. Same origin policy issue

Comment: here i am not using web service right.?but you are suggested link shows web service stuff.Is this link suitable for my query Non-HTTP synchronous request https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Usar_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Same origin policy is not based on synchronous or asynchronous requests. my one suggestion in above link is do the loading sample.xml part in the serverside and expose a service or page method that can access using javascript. So that will be inside the same domain and you can access it without any issue.