# jsfiddle - Simple Ajax request

Tags: jquery

I am just a beginner with jquery and am trying to call simple request. Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xVrNL/

I am using this code:

```
HTML:
<button>Click me</button>
```

and

```
jQuery:
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://jsfiddle.net/echo/html/",
        success: function(result) {
            alert("Data: " + result);
        }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work. Reading documentation doesn't help me. Can anybody suggest solution?

Thank you very much

........

Comment: First of all, you have to pick jQuery library from the left sidebar :)

Comment: Do you see the first select box on the left side? It says *"No-Library (pure JS)"*. You have to change it and select to include jQuery. Please read the documentation (of anything) before you use it: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the reasons for your problem:

1. You have to refer the jQuery library reference for the jsfiddle
2. You cant use absolute urls for ajax requests. Please refer the following answer for more information.

[$.ajax call working fine in IE8 and Doesn't work in firefox and chrome browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698682/ajax-call-working-fine-in-ie8-and-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-chrome-browsers/8698786#8698786)

Comment: I didn't know about not using absolute urls, thanks

Comment: edited to correct english

Answer (score 1):

You need to import latest jQuery library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xVrNL/2/  .See this link it is working now

Comment: Or you could pick jQuery in the sidebar...

Answer (score 0):

1. Set jquery from the left sidebar
2. remove the domain from "url"

Example jsfiddle.net/xVrNL/3/

(sorry it's not a link but I keep getting a message saying it has to be wrapped with a code even when it was..)

Result: [image]

Comment: after removing domain, alert popped up, but it returned no data

Comment: Because there's no data, it's just an echo

Comment: You have to put some code directly on your post to have a Fiddle link.

Comment: I did try that as well.. :/